# Reversible paste with final empty string in R

Tags: r, string

I need to store vectors of strings into a file and then later reload them. Since this file will need to be (somewhat) human readable/editable and readable by other languages, I cannot simply use `saveRDS` to store these.

The vectors of strings have variable length, and sometimes end in an empty string. Is there a way to use `paste` and `strsplit` reversibly when the input vector of strings has a final empty string entry?

```
x <- c("", "a", "b", "")
y <- paste(x, collapse = ",")

> x
[1] ""  "a" "b" ""

> y
[1] ",a,b,"

> strsplit(y, ",")[[1]]
[1] ""  "a" "b"
```

Basically, I'd rather the process not eat the final empty string since it does carry useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `scan` instead:

```
scan(text=y, what='', sep=',')
# [1] ""  "a" "b" ""
```

Comment: Nice! Glad to not have to load another package.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to always add an empty string at the end when pasting. Is there a better way?

```
paste2 <- function(stringVec, collapse) paste(c(stringVec,""), collapse=collapse)

> strsplit(paste2(x, collapse=","),",")[[1]]
[1] ""  "a" "b" ""
```

Comment: I believe that `str_split` from the **stringr** package behaves in the way you want (i.e. will include the trailing empty string when splitting).